# matplotlib x axis on top interference with the title

Tags: python, matplotlib

in the following post (number 23) : Moving x-axis to the top of a plot in matplotlib, the answer to move the x-axis on top is given. But it does not say anything about the title.

I have a plot with a x-axis on top and a title, but the x label interfers with my title. How can I separate the xlabel from the title ?

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a minimal working example of your code and describe the error as abundant as possible. And also, post your outcome and desired outcome as well. Without that, no one could be able to help you with your problem...

Comment: Hi, ok sorry ! next time I ll have an question about the code, I ll write down the code and the outcomes. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `y` kwarg for `ax.set_title`. Experiment with the value of `y` to suit your needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()

ax1.set_title('Title1')
ax2.set_title('Title2',y=1.05)

fig.savefig('title.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you very much for your quick answer. It is working perfectly :)